# What is SQL Connection

Tags: sql, .net

What ***SQL Connection object*** is and what does actually happen when we open/close it? What resources does it consume and why is it necessary to dispose it (in terms of c#/.net)?

Comment: Have you read MSDN (especially the remarks section)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(v=vs.110).aspx You should also read all about [Connection-Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Nothing better than looking at the source code [SqlConnection.cs](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs) Good Luck

Comment: @tim yes, I have. The article just says "it's an object that represents a session". How does it do it? What ACTUALLY happens inside this object? Please don't send me to google - I've been there, I've also been at SO Search Engine.

Comment: @steve thanks. The only thing I forgot about was the referencesource.

Comment: Too many people take the concept of "connection" for granted, but I think explicitly stating what is actually involved both in terms of client and server resources would be helpful. Also, why did people assume this question is MS SQL Server specific? Voting to reopen.

Comment: Please ask specific questions in future. A question _"What is SQL-Connection?"_ calls for a tutorial or documentation which is off-topic on stackoverflow. Instead search on your own first and ask questions regarding specific programming issues.

Comment: @BrankoDimitrijevic: This question is far from being on-topic on SO, also, _SQL Connection_ is probably just another word for `SqlConnection`. And if it's not, it's all the more "too broad".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SqlConnection:**
Take a look at [the MSDN page for SqlConnection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). It is stated that:

> A SqlConnection object represents a unique session to a SQL Server
>    data source. With a client/server database system, it is equivalent to
>    a network connection to the server.

**SqlConnection.Open:** In the [MSDN page on SqlConnection.Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.open(v=vs.110).aspx), it is stated that:

> The SqlConnection draws an open connection from the connection pool if
>    one is available. Otherwise, it establishes a new connection to an
>    instance of SQL Server.

**SqlConnection.Close(and Dispose):**

[The MSDN page on SqlConnection.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.close%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) says that:

> The Close method rolls back any pending transactions. It then releases the connection to the connection pool, or closes the connection if connection pooling is disabled.

Also, in the SqlConnection page it is stated that:

> If the SqlConnection goes out of scope, it won't be closed. Therefore, you must explicitly close the connection by calling Close or Dispose. Close and Dispose are functionally equivalent. If the connection pooling value Pooling is set to true or yes, the underlying connection is returned back to the connection pool. On the other hand, if Pooling is set to false or no, the underlying connection to the server is actually closed.

and:

> To ensure that connections are always closed, open the connection inside of a using block, as shown in the following code fragment. Doing so ensures that the connection is automatically closed when the code exits the block.

This should answer your questions.

EDIT:
For further readings (also seen in your comments) you can read about [Connection-Pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and of course check out the [source code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Data/data/System/Data/SqlClient/SqlConnection.cs) for SqlConnection.

Comment: thanks for your answer, @tobypls. These two last links in your 'edit' section are exactly what I had to find myself, but didn't know how to formulate the question I wanted to get an answer for.

Comment: Okey great! If my answer contained what you were searching for, don't forget to mark it as accepted.

Comment: Kind of, but the answering parts of the "manuals" are quoted in the answer so he doesn't have to read the manuals. But of course, for more depth in the areas, one has to rtfm.

Comment: @tim well I marked the post as the answer just because of the 'edit' - those two links gave me answers to the question. tim after you've added a link to connection pools article I found the answers there. Of course before asking here I googled 'sql connection object', but I've found only msdn's_article_about_sql_connection like articles which stated that 'that is a special object giving us the possibility to query the db and have methods to work with it'. I didn't have an idea to search for connection pool, and SO helped me to get it. So yes, the answer is - rtfm, but pls specify what 'm' ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sql Connection object in an object which we create using Sql connection class which belongs to System.Data.SqlClient namespace. We use Sql Connection object to execute sql commands in sql server database.

Close and Dispose are two different things. You can reuse the connection if you close it but not after dispose it.

It is always a good practice to open the connection just before you want it and close it once done your needs.

In c#, the connection will be disposed if you create the connection with “using” statement.